# How do i make an user write in an object name from an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, menu

sorry for my begginner level question, i tried to look up this issue here but all of them were above my skill level to understand.

Basically i first want to show the user the content of an object array.
After that the user will write down names from the array and the program will copy those names into an empty object array of equal size, untill it is full.

This is how my class object looks like:

```
public class MyClass //Edit for better clarity
{
  private string name;
  private int price;
  private string type;

 Public string Name
  {
   get {return name;}
   set {name = value;}
  }

 public int Price
  {
   get {return price;}
   set {price = value;}
  }

 public string Type
  {
   get {return type;}
   set {type = value;}
  }

 public MyClass(string _name, int _price, string _type)
 {
    name = _name;
    price = _price;
    type = _type;
 }

}
```

And this is where i assign a new class and create the objects

```
public class Inventory
{   

    Myclass[] alternative = new MyClass[5]; // From this will be copied
    MyClass[] storage = new MyClass[5]; //And here it will be copied to
```

So how do i best make an user type in the object name and then copy it to the other array and store it?

Comment: You should not use the name `Object` for a custom class: it's very confusing.

Comment: What do you mean with `how do i best make an user type in the object name`? `Console.ReadLine()?` `TextBox`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes through Console.ReadLine() preferably. And i realise my class name "object" is a bad one too.  I made it as an example since my actual project has other names in my own language so i thought id change them to English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to get an Object by it's proprerty Name.

First of all, you shouldn't be using this name for your class, since `Object` is a class from the System namespace.

Second, since you said you are a begginner, I will give you a tip:
You can use auto-properties instead of declaring a private field and a property that only gets/sets it without doing something special. I recommend you to look it up!

Okay, now to your question: (I will rename `Object` to `anObject`)

```
        anObject[] alternative = new anObject[5]; // From this will be copied
        anObject[] storage = new anObject[5]; //And here it will be copied to

        /* display the alternative anObject array (via loop)*/

        int storageIndex = 0;

        // Get the name
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); // Or use any other way you want

        // Iterate over initial aray
        for (int i = 0; i < alternative.Length; i++)
        {
            if(alternative != null) // Make sure it exists
            {
                if (userInput == alternative[i].Name)
                    storage[storageIndex++] = alternative[i];
            }
        }
```

This code will get you one anObject into the `storage`. All you have to do now is iterate as many times you want.

Comment: Yes that works well. Will this new value be saved for other  methods in my Inventory class?  For exampel "remove item" or "show items"? And thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MasterKjK, I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you're asking wheter other fuctions will be able to access this array, the short answer is yes.

In order to do that, you need to declare the 'storage' global or to pass that array as a parameter to other functions.
You should also be careful with all this, I recommend you to read about Reference vs Value types.

Not trying to be rude or anything, but I strongly advise you to get a good book about programming because your base seems quite weak.